# Excel SUMPRODUCT with criteria on Named Range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how to sum a named range (rng_charged_main) with 2 criteria: 1. only if the delivered date ("rng_dateDeliverd_main") is a certain month and 2. It should match the selected client ("SelectedClient").

You can't use SUMIFS because you can't extract the MONTH('n') in the SUMIFS criteria.

The SUMPRODUCT works well only with ONE criteria when I used ranges like A2:A15 but will not work when I use named ranges or the table itself.

So this works but is not what I need:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O2:O3618)*(MONTH(N2:N3618)=11))
```

But even the above will not work when I add the second criteria (matching the selected client cell) like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((O3390:O3611)*(MONTH(N3390:N3611)=11)*(C3390:C3641=C5))
```

Using the table and column names gives me an error *"A Value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"*

```
=SUMPRODUCT((tbl_main[Charged])*(MONTH(tbl_main[Date Finished])=11)*(rng_clients_main=SelectedClient))
```

Using Named Ranges gives me an error *"A Value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"*

```
=SUMPRODUCT((rng_charged_main)*(MONTH(rng_dateFinished_main)=11)*(rng_clients_main=SelectedClient))
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: How about using an intermediary column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think check that your ranges are the same length and data types in each column are the same. I have no problem when using the column names

```
=SUMPRODUCT((tbl_main[Charged])*(MONTH(tbl_main[Date Finished])=F3)*(tbl_main[rng_clients_main]=SelectedClient))
```

[image]

Comment: This is very strange. When I made a new test sheet and copied the data and formula like you posted, it works fine. But when I use the same formula on my real table, I get #VALUE with error ""A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type". I double checked and the entire range of dates is data-type date and the "charged" are all currency. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Step one - highlight sections of your formula and use F9 to work out which part is producing the error.

Comment: My table has 3641 rows. When I try to press F9, I get an error saying that I can't use more than 8192 characters. I guess I'll have to copy the table to a test sheet and delete rows to test this. I'll update you after I do this.

Comment: Yeah. Or create a copy of the same workbook and delete rows from that to keep as much the same as possible.

Comment: Found the problematic row! Is was row 2019 which had the date value of 39-5-16 lol Everything works now. Thanks!